# Converting seconds to hours,minutes and seconds

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been trying to make a web app that converts seconds to hours/minutes/seconds but with no luck. I can't figure out how to do this at all, i created over a dozen c# projects but none works with any code i try and i also do not understand the creation of such thing. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me create this form.

Comment: Could you post some Code what you already tried and where you get problems?

Comment: "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Comment: I presume you have the mathematics correct ? is this just a coding issue ?

Comment: Take a look at [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx), then if you have further problems, ask a good question based on that.

Comment: It seems simple maths, why you can't got answer ? please post your error so we can solve.

Answer (score 8):

```
int seconds = 1000;
TimeSpan timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
int hour = timespan.Hours;
int min = timespan.Minutes;
int sec = timespan.Seconds;
```

Comment: As C# is a strongly typed language, it is also worth noting that `var` is not necessary and can be replaced with the actual variable types if preferred

Comment: Its just a convenience thing - you're right they could all just be int etc.  It means if you have long types you end up with a shorter line of code eg ALongTypeName a = new ALongTypeName();  Its entirely clear what the type is so I use var.  It also means I don't have think what the actual type is when writing the code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple aritmetic, for example:

```
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;

seconds = 12351;
hours = (int)(Math.Floor((double)(seconds / 3600)));
seconds = seconds % 3600;
minutes = (int)(Math.Floor((double)(seconds / 60)));
seconds = seconds % 60;
string time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

If there should be a leading zero on the hours, the final line can also be changed to

```
string time = (hours.ToString().Length == 1 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(500000);
var totalMinutesInTimeSpan = timeSpan.TotalMinutes;
```